# Change text in text box when something is dragged (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want to change the text in the text box when different images is dragged. However, I'm not so sure how to do the function for it. If anyone can help me an example of this, that'd be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

So far I only have the var of textfield and var of the textformat

var onStart:TextField = new TextField();
var onFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();

```
    onStart.x = 76;
    onStart.y = 60;
    onStart.width = 162;
    onStart.height = 68;
    onFormat.font = "Calibri";
    onFormat.size = 30;
    onStart.defaultTextFormat = onFormat;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP listener to each image (indicating the user has stopped dragging the image) and change onStart.text when the event is fired.

```
image1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, changeText);
image2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, changeText);
image3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, changeText);

function changeText(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    switch(e.target)
    {
        case image1:
            onStart.text = "image 1";
            break;
        case image2:
            onStart.text = "image 2";
            break;
        case image3:
            onStart.text = "image 3";
            break;
        default:
            break;
     }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jacob, thanks a lot! 
However, I'm thinking more of a switch statement or If else statement due to multiple images I have.